# onchange is not working in both internal and inline script.why?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to fire a function when select box is changed.I am trying both inline script and internal script.please check my code...

```
inline script:
```

```html
    <script>
    function show()
    {
        alert("show");
    }
    </script>
    <select name="registerAs" id="registerAs" onchange="show()">
     <option value="register as">register as</option>
  <option value="doctor">doctor</option>
  <option value="patient">patient</option>
  <option value="pharmacy">pharmacy</option>
 </select>
```

```
internal script
```

```html
    <script>
    window.onload = function()
    {
        document.getElementById("registerAs").onchange = function()
        {
            alert("show");
        }
    }
    </script>
    <select name="registerAs" id="registerAs">
     <option value="register as">register as</option>
  <option value="doctor">doctor</option>
  <option value="patient">patient</option>
  <option value="pharmacy">pharmacy</option>
 </select>
```

i am unable to to understand why this is not working.

Comment: It works. You must have some other problem.

Comment: When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide functional example that people can use to reproduce the problem. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You can also click `<>` icon in the header in edit mode to add a demo. Thanks!

Comment: **NOTE:** To prove you that your code works, I have edited the question and wrapped your code in stack snippets. Other than adding a missing `>` (which doesn't seem to be the problem, only the first snipped missed it and you said both snippets don't work), I **changed nothing** in your code: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49584641/revisions

Comment: It is working in both the snippets you added. Error must be somewhre else in your code

Comment: Use the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and read any errors.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me, but using inline event handlers is bad practice and results in poorly factored, hard-to-manage code - it's as bad as `eval`. Seriously consider attaching your events with JavaScript, instead, eg: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener.

If you have issues, try something like this instead, keeping the Javascript in the Javascript alone, and the HTML in the HTML - separate presentation from content:

```js
// in a separate .js file:
document.querySelector("#registerAs").addEventListener('change', () => {
  alert("show");
});
```

```html
<select name="registerAs" id="registerAs">
<option value="register as">register as</option>
<option value="doctor">doctor</option>
<option value="patient">patient</option>
<option value="pharmacy">pharmacy</option>
</select>
```

When you use inline or on*- properties, you're restricting yourself to only one handler per event - you're overwriting whatever property was on the element before.